# How to safely build mailto link in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How to create an `Uri` instance containing a `mailto:` link in ASP.NET 6/C# so it is immune to mailicious user input?

```cs
@{
  var email = @"test@example.com"; // Unsafe value - supplied by a user

  var linkTitle = email;
  var linkDestination = new Uri("mailto:" + email); // Replace with a safer approach
}

<!-- Intended usage - should not need to care whether its an e-mail or web link -->
<a href="@linkDestination">@linkTitle</a>
```

Comment: There are different kinds of `mailto:` addresses, e.g. some formats allow you to specify a subject and message-body (not just the To: address), which one are you using?

Comment: Razor's `@` only does HTML encoding, but that's largely all you need to do to defend against XSS attacks - are you also concerned about the correct URL-encoding to use?

Comment: 1) This time, just the e-mail address, no subject, no message body. 2) I'm concerned about how to do it properly. If HTML encoding is enough (i. e. the original example is safe), I'm ok with it. If there is anything else to care about, I'd love to become aware of it.

Answer (score -2):

You should validate your email variable, if this is a valid email.

One way to do this is to use regexp.

Another way is to use a [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EmailAddressAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.emailaddressattribute.aspx)
starting from .Net 4.5:

```
string email = @"test@example.com";
bool isValidEmail = email != null && new EmailAddressAttribute().IsValid(email);
```

Hope, this will help.

Comment: This does not protect against XSS attacks.

Comment: The question is about C#, so topic starter already has a variable email  with a string containing email address.

Comment: If the protection is needed before (on the web-page where user provides email, then author's question is incorrect.

Comment: No previous protection is relevant - a filled string variable is the input of this code; it's out of scope how the e-mail address appears in it.

Comment: @alik Then my answer is correct

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper No, it's not. Besides, the `EmailAddressAttribute()` was **severely nerfed** [to the point of being flat-out incorrect and useless for validating e-mail addresses since .NET Core:](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/65968)